# How do I do simple conditional calling in Twilio based on time of day?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, twilio, twilio-twiml

How do I easily, without complex code, redirect a number in Twilio based on time of day?
At 8;30 am I want the number to redirect to me
at 6:30 pm I want the number to redirect to employee b
at 1:00am I want the number to redirect to the call center?
At weekends from 6:30pm onwards, i want to redirect to the call center
The numbers could be fixed in the code as variables. Just need something to take the hassle out of manually switching who takes calls several times a day.

How do I do this easily without too much coding?
I have basic Python skills, but would be great if I could do this as a Twiml.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568121/twilio-call-forwarding-for-specific-time-of-day ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio call forwarding for specific time of day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568121/twilio-call-forwarding-for-specific-time-of-day)

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert suggests, you can achieve this as implied in this question:

[Twilio call forwarding for specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568121/twilio-call-forwarding-for-specific-time-of-day)

You can't manipulate the time directly in [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), but using your favorite Python framework and time module you could code your own solution where `response = "<Dial><Number>A_PHONE_NUMBER_FOR_GIVEN_TIME</Number></Dial>"` is set for the appropriate number at the appropriate time.

I also found [this example on Github](https://github.com/plaidfluff/BagelVoice/commit/82521c52d434a955b124e50905f8cc58382503d9) which is likely overkill given your scenario but interesting nonetheless.